# How to merge two condition in mysql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I am new in mysql and php. I want to know how two query merge in mysql. I have table *testTable* in which :

```
id     Username1    USername2
1      A            A
2      A            B
3      B            A
4      A            A
5      A            C
6      B            A
7      A            B
8      A            A
```

Now I want to write query: (A and B) Or (B ana  A) shows in table only.

Like

```
2     A     B   
3     B     A
6     B     A
7     A     B
```

thats I want but as I am new so I am not able to do this.

I tried this

```
$query  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableWriteText WHERE txt_Userame1='$txt_Useram1' AND txt_Userame2='$txt_Userame2'  ORDER BY id ");
```

And send from iphone to php and get

suppose I send from iPhone `username1 = A` , `username2 = B`

So I get the table

```
2   A       B
7   A       B
```

But I want whenever I send from iPhone `username1 = A` , `username2 = B`

or

Second time I send from iPhone `username1 = B` , `username2 = A`

Every time, I want to get all A and B  table by order like

```
2     A     B   
3     B     A
6     B     A
7     A     B
```

For this I tried also this:

```
$query  = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tableWriteText WHERE (txt_Userame1='$txt_Useram1' AND txt_Userame2='$txt_Userame2')  OR  (txt_Userame2='$txt_Useram2' AND txt_Userame1='$txt_Userame1')  ORDER BY id ");
```

Any idea or suggestions would be highly welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query you have written in the last is almost correct. Just a logical issue is there.

```
(txt_Userame1='$txt_Useram1' AND txt_Userame2='$txt_Userame2')  
OR  
(txt_Userame2='$txt_Useram2' AND txt_Userame1='$txt_Userame1')
```

You have just change the order in which they are appearing, You also need to swipe the variables.

This might be useful for you...

```
"SELECT * FROM tableWriteText WHERE (txt_Userame1 = '$txt_Useram1' AND txt_Userame2 = '$txt_Userame2')  OR  (txt_Userame1 = '$txt_Useram2' AND txt_Userame2 = '$txt_Userame1') ORDER BY id "
```

Comment: its giving only  A   and  B combination. I want A and B , B and A combination both.

Answer (score 0):

You should add one more conditions to the query:

```
SELECT * FROM tableWriteText
WHERE
txt_Userame1='$txt_Useram1' AND txt_Userame2='$txt_Userame2'
OR
txt_Userame1='$txt_Userame2' AND txt_Userame2='$txt_Useram1'
ORDER BY id, asc
```

`AND` has higher priority than `OR`, so you don't have to use brakets here.